# Is the Tumblrs theme-system somehow copyright-protected?

Tags: templates, template-engine, tumblr

I'm creating a small service, which needs to have ability for custom themes. I like the way Tumblr handles them, and would like to know, if it's legal to just plain copy their way.

```
{Block:Post}
   {Block:Title}<h1>{Title}</h1>{/Block:Title}
{/Block:Post}
```

Does someone know something about this? Would it be bad reputation?

Martti Laine

Comment: I agree with you. I'm just wondering if it would "flag" my service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a lawyer, but I strongly doubt whether this kind of pattern can be copyright protected in *any* jurisdiction. (It's just the pattern syntax you want to copy, correct?)

As to bad reputation: Nah. Not inventing a new template language is a *great* idea, because there will be one thing less to learn.

I think't it's perfectly all right to use this, and I can not think of a reason why Tumblr wouldn't like it.

But if it really worries you and you want to make totally, totally sure, you can always ask them, or use e.g.

```
<Block:Post>
   <Block:Title><h1><Title></h1></Block:Title>
</Block:Post>
```

but it arguably doesn't look as pretty as yours.